# Ratio between count of individual rows and aggregated column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have data 1 in following format:

| Header | value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 1 |
| D | 1 |
| D | 1 |
| D | 1 |
| D | 1 |
| D | 1 |
| D | 1 |
| D | 1 |

and data 2 in following format

| Header | Count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| B | 20 |
| C | 20 |
| D | 20 |

I am expecting to create a table visual in power bi which will give me following output

| header | data1_value | data2_count | final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 8 | 10 | 0.8 |
| B | 9 | 20 | 0.45 |
| C | 9 | 20 | 0.45 |
| D | 8 | 10 | 0.8 |

Can you help me to write a DAX measure to achieve final column

Comment: Do you have relationships set up? Share a snip of your Data Model so we can see table names and relationships etc....

Comment: Do you want a measure, a calculated table or a calculated column? Are there any relationships between tables?

Answer (score 0):

Create a relationship between Table_1 (Raw level data table) and Table_2 (Count table) using Header column. And create below three measures.

```
count_header =  COUNT(Table_1[value])
count_count = COUNT(Table_2[Count])
final = DIVIDE(count_header ,count_count ,0)
```